# "Told you!", but non-gender-neutral

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, gender-positive

There is a Russian comedy playback show, and I am trying to translate several funny fragments of it.

There is a married couple. The wife dislikes the friends of the family and is annoyed by them, but the husband is more affable. The friends turn out to be rather self-serving, so the wife, portrayed by a man, goes "I told you!" (It's a men's troupe doing improvisational theatre.)

The problem is that past tense verbs in Russian have gender morphemes and that the actor gets pretty emotional, so his line is actually more like "I have told-male! Told-female"—the actor forgot for a second that he was playing a woman and used the wrong verb—and the husband is playing surprised.

What is the best way to play with it in English? I thought of something like "A-ha, who's Mister Told-Ya?" or "Mister I-Knew-So", but doesn't it seem too self-ironic for the situation? Also, is the definite article needed before "Mister"?

Comment: I don't understand the context. *Why* is the wife portrayed by a man? (I assume they're not a *gay* couple! :) Would it make any difference if both the husband and wife were played by *women*?

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's a men's troupe, doing improvisational theatre. The actor forgot for a second that he was playing a woman, and used the wrong verb :)

Comment: oic - but that might be a context where there's no equivalent in modern English! Something like that *could* have arisen in Britain in Shakespeare's time (when women weren't *allowed* to be actors). And *maybe* there might be a gag in this general area in [Upstart Crow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart_Crow) - where "Kate" (Gemma Whelan) is Shakespeare's friend who ends up rewriting and polishing some of the Bard's most memorable lines. But I think it's a culture-specific thing that won't translate well because of *cultural* as well as language differences.

Comment: It's only really spoken facetiously today, but only men normally say/said ***Don't you worry your pretty little head about it**!* Maybe you could work something around [*Behind every successful man there's](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/behind-every-great-successful-man-there-stands-a-woman) [another man?!]*

Comment: There are certain terms usually used by men to address other men (like "bro") but they don't really fit here.

Comment: Still don't get why *Told you so* isn't good enough in English.

Comment: Possibly something like "Told you! Listen to your man!" (or "wife" instead of "man" for the opposite version). However, this is writing advice and primarily opinion-based. There is no "best" way to phrase it to make it non-gender-neutral. Perhaps, it is a question for https://writing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ermanen Thanks for both the answer and the link!

Comment: Unfortunately, it can be quite difficult to translate wordplay like this. See https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/277402/american-gods-how-is-this-crucial-word-translated-in-non-english-translations for an example of a joke that doesn't translate well.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to have the wife address the husband in a way more typically associated with male friends, and then immediately try to correct it:

> I told you this would happen, dude!—I mean, *my darling husband.*